# Install kubernetes manually with cri-o

Tags: installation, kubernetes

I am trying to install Kubernetes on CentOS boxes and using crio as container runtime. Kubelet service is not coming online. It seems it is trying to find docker and not recognizing crio. I tried to change cgroup for kubeadm with the hope that it might solve the issue but could not find how to do so. I am following directions from kubernetes.io but they are not that clear.

Is there any detailed technical documentation about how to do so? Any help is much appreciated.

Rgrds, ~t

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends on how you're starting Kubelet. Check your arguments.

Using containerd, as deployed by kube-spray, I would have something like this:

```
# cat /etc/crictl.yaml 
runtime-endpoint: unix:///var/run/containerd/containerd.sock
image-endpoint: unix:///var/run/containerd/containerd.sock
timeout: 30
debug: false
# cat /etc/kubernetes/kubelet.env
[...]
KUBELET_ARGS="[...] \
--container-runtime=remote \
--container-runtime-endpoint=unix:///var/run/containerd/containerd.sock \
```

Try setting those couple arguments, pointing to whichever socket your crictl configuration shows.